# UITableView height inside UIScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, height

I'm trying to add a `UITableView` inside `UIScrollView` but when I set the height of `UITableView` using ***`tableView.contentSize.height`*** it is not setting the height properly (It add extra height to whats actual height is)

Can anyone Please help?

[image: This is what I want to achieve]

Comment: why are you adding tableview on scrollview? UITableView is also a sub class of UIScrollView.

Comment: is not a good think to work bro, tableview is subclass of scrollview

Comment: use any one it suerly fit for the view

Comment: Consider using tableHeaderView and tableFooterView properties of UITableView.

Comment: What exactly I want to achieve is
I have two list that needs to be displayed on below the other separated through a uilabel
Above and below these lists are various stuffs
So with header and footer view i cant achieve this

Comment: And why not making 2 sections?

Comment: Why do you need to adjust the content size of tableview.? Content size will be automatically adjusted according the number of cells and its height. Are trying to change the frame height?

Comment: Do the `tableviews` need to be scrolled individually, one scrolls while the other sits still, otherwise just go with two sections as @derdida suggests.

Comment: @derdida I have one view above the tableview that scrolls horizontally

Comment: @good4pc could you please tell me how to do 
I am new to iOS

Comment: Can u make a Screen how it should look like?

Comment: he mean: tableView.frame.height

Comment: @derdida I have edited the question

Comment: @good4pc frame height is a get only property

Comment: I would like to make ALL this with 1 UITableView. Just make some Custom Cells.

Comment: Thanks @derdida will consider that

Comment: Try this to set frame:         let table = UITableView()
        table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 400)

Answer (score 1):

I am able to make the content size of table to set as table height and modify the content size of scrollView by following way.

I just designed the table inside the scrollView and call to modify the height of table and content size of scrollView from `viewDidAppear`

**My Code :**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.extraDesignAfterStoryboard();
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.modifyContentHeight();
}

func extraDesignAfterStoryboard()
{
    scrolVw = UIScrollView();
    scrolVw.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
    scrolVw.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
    self.view.addSubview(scrolVw);

    tblViewScr = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 80, scrolVw.frame.size.width, 120), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain);
    tblViewScr.delegate = self;
    tblViewScr.tag = 100;
    tblViewScr.dataSource = self;
    tblViewScr.scrollEnabled = false;
    tblViewScr.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
    scrolVw.addSubview(tblViewScr);
}

func modifyContentHeight()
{
    if(self.tblViewScr.contentSize.height > self.tblViewScr.frame.height){
        var frame: CGRect = self.tblViewScr.frame;
        frame.size.height = self.tblViewScr.contentSize.height;
        self.tblViewScr.frame = frame;

        var contentSize = self.scrolVw.contentSize;
        contentSize.height = CGRectGetMaxY(self.tblViewScr.frame);
        self.scrolVw.contentSize = contentSize;
    }
}
```

It is working here in my Demo project.
Can you check once, If it works for you.

Comment: Where did you get the datasource? See I have designed in viewDidLoad and calling to modify the frame in viewDidAppear.
Actually you need to call the method after your table has data loaded. Did you get my point?? Are you doing the same ?

Comment: Are you setting the content size of scrollView like this see in code.

        var contentSize = self.scrolVw.contentSize;
        contentSize.height = CGRectGetMaxY(self.tblViewScr.frame);
        self.scrolVw.contentSize = contentSize;